# Comma Separated List From Properties File As Constructor Argument in Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am trying to use below spring injection for list of strings.

```
<bean name="myBean" class="java.util.HashSet">
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.Collection" value="#{'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',')}"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting String `"'${my.list.of.strings}'.split(',')"` as constructor argument instead of List of Strings.

Is there any Version Issue?

I am using Spring Release 2.5, spring-beans 2.0.xsd

Answer (score 1):

If your bean wasn't a `HashSet` and had a constructor that accepted an array as an argument, you could do something like this:

```
<bean name="myBean" class="mypackage.MyBeanClass">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String[]" value="${my.list.of.strings}" />
</bean>
```

Or this:

```
<bean name="myBean" class="mypackage.MyBeanClass">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value type="java.lang.String[]">${my.list.of.strings}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

(I don't remember which is the correct way for Spring 2.5, actually I don't remember if you can even use a placeholder. If this is the case, please consider using the last version of Spring, which by these days is 4.1.5.RELEASE).

But you want `myBean` bean to be of class `HashSet`. The only solution I can think of is to use your own class that wraps `HashSet` or maybe extends from it:

```
package mypackage;

// imports ommited

public class MyBeanClass extends HashSet<String> {

    public MyBeanClass(String[] values) {
        super(Arrays.asList(values));
    }
}
```

If you don't like the idea to inherit directly from `HashSet`, then wrap it and make the wrapper delegate all the methods you want to it:

```
package mypackage;

// imports ommited

public class MyBeanClass implements Set<String> {

    private final Set<String> delegate;

    public MyBeanClass(String[] values) {
        this.delegate = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(values));
    }

    public boolean add(String element) {
        return this.delegate.add(element);
    }

    public boolean contains(Object element) {
        return this.delegate.contains(element);
    }

    // TODO rest of delegate methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Expression Language (spring-el) only appeared in Spring 3.0. Your expressions aren't going to be evaluated with Spring 2.5, you'll need to do that a different way.

Even with Spring 3, I'd recommend finding another way to build your set, such as using a `FactoryBean` (see [Customizing instantiation logic using FactoryBeans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean))